# Drawing horizontal line in printed pdf using UIPrintPageRenderer

Tags: ios, printing, drawing, uiprintpagerenderer

I'm using UIPrintPageRenderer sub-class to print html content on a pdf. How can i add a horizontal line on my printed content (both on header and footer)?

`CGContextAddLineToPoint` doesn't seem to work in UIPrintPageRenderer methods. Specifically those used to draw header and footer. NSString's drawAtPoint is working perfectly.

Here's what i've tried so far:

```
- (void)drawHeaderForPageAtIndex:(NSInteger)pageIndex inRect:(CGRect)headerRect {
    ...

    // Attempt 1 (Doesn't work!)
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1);
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 10.0, 20.0);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 310.0, 20.0);

    // Attempt 2 (Doesn't work!)
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1);
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1);

    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, headerRect.size.height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1, -1);

    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 10.0, 20.0);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 310.0, 20.0);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, for now i've applied an alternate solution. I would still love to know how to do this using CGContext (without having to load an image). Here's my solution:

```
// Draw horizontal ruler in the header
UIImage *horizontalRule = [UIImage imageNamed:@"HorizontalRule.png"];
horizontalRule = [horizontalRule stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0.5 topCapHeight:0];

CGFloat rulerX = CGRectGetMinX(headerRect) + HEADER_LEFT_TEXT_INSET;
CGFloat rulerY = self.printableRect.origin.y + fontSize.height + HEADER_FOOTER_MARGIN_PADDING + PRINT_RULER_MARGIN_PADDING;
CGFloat rulerWidth = headerRect.size.width - HEADER_LEFT_TEXT_INSET - HEADER_RIGHT_TEXT_INSET;
CGFloat rulerHeight = 1;
CGRect ruleRect = CGRectMake(rulerX, rulerY, rulerWidth, rulerHeight);

[horizontalRule drawInRect:ruleRect blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:1.0];
```

Comment: can we use custom UI, UI Contains two UIElemnts in header section ,?

Answer (score 1):

In Core Graphics, a logical graphics elements are added to the context and then drawn. I see you adding a path to the context with e.g. `CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 310.0, 20.0);`

This creates the path in memory, but to composite it to the screen you need to either fill or stroke the context's path. Try adding `CGContextStrokePath(context);` after to actually stoke the path.

Answer (score 1):

Just as regular drawing

```
- (void)drawHeaderForPageAtIndex:(NSInteger)pageIndex inRect:(CGRect)headerRect {

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CContextMoveToPoint(context, CGRectGetMinX(headerRect), 70);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, CGRectGetMaxX(headerRect), 70);

    CGFloat grayScale = 0.5f;
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, grayScale, grayScale, grayScale, 1);

    CGContextStrokePath(context);
}
```

Don't forget to `CGStrokePath(...)`